# Symbol list definition for XML

Tags: xml, sublimetext3, symbols

Using Sublime Text 3, I have been working on getting a symbol list definition for XML files that looks good.

So far I have achieved something workable. For this XML example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definition assembly="com.bla" version="1.0">
    <string name="parent"/>
        <child name="child" />
    </string>
</definition>
```

I can get:

[image: Symbols]

Using:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>name</key>
    <string>Symbol List:</string>
    <key>scope</key>
    <string>text.xml meta.tag.xml</string>
    <key>settings</key>
    <dict>
        <key>showInIndexedSymbolList</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
        <key>showInSymbolList</key>
        <integer>1</integer>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, I would like to indent the child under the parent and also remove the closing tags. Are these possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need [the XML syntax definition to scope closing tags differently](https://github.com/sublimehq/Packages/issues/442) to be able to exclude them from the symbol list, as the logic which dictates what gets placed in the symbol list is based solely on the scopes assigned by the syntax definition. i.e. assuming you modified the [syntax definition](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/syntax.html) to scope closing tags as `meta.tag.xml.closing`, your scope selector could look like `<string>text.xml meta.tag.xml - meta.tag.xml.closing</string>`, and you'd get only the opening (and self closing) tags.

---

As for indentation, this is usually done by using [regex transformations](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/symbols.html#text-transformations), which isn't really designed for recursive nesting as there is generally not enough context available for the regex replacements to work on.

One workaround would be to again modify the syntax definition to apply a meta scope to the contents of each tag, and have multiple `tmPreferences` files to each operate on a more specific nesting than the previous one, and just hard-code the indentation, but this would be limited to how many files you create for how much nesting is handled correctly, but it would work regardless of the layout of the XML file.

If your XML files are nicely indented already (- and there are plugins for this, if not -) then you may be able to achieve what you want by changing the syntax definition to scope the whitespace before the open tags. Scoping it as `meta.tag` may interfere with some of ST's built in commands that rely on this scope, so maybe it would be better to add a separate scope that covers the whitespace and the tag itself, leaving the original `meta.tag` scopes intact. Using this approach, the symbol would already contain the same indentation from the file, and you could potentially convert 4 spaces to 1, for example, to make the symbol index not appear as indented as the main document.

Comment: Thanks a lot Keith, I would have to try these out. I will +1 the issues that you have pointed out, it is quite a shame that XML handling is not even supported out of the box.